# how to calculate the distance between two points and find the fare accordingly

Tags: android, algorithm, google-maps, math

```
            jcJobNo.setText(Contsants.Jobno);
    jcStartTime.setText(Contsants.jobStartTime);
    jcEndTime.setText(Contsants.jobEndTime);

    // total distance finding here
    float totalKm = Contsants.jobEndKm-Contsants.jobStartKm;
    jcTotalKms.setText(Float.toString(totalKm));

    //jcTotalKms.setText(Float.toString((float) (totalKm/16.0)));
    //finding total fare here
    float totalfare=totalKm *16;
    jcTotalFare.setText(Float.toString(totalfare));
```

here is a simple code for calculating the distance between two points and calculate the fare according to the distance. But i din't get exact fare value and the output is in negative. I don't know how to resolve this error. If any one knows please help me.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html and read `distanceBetween (double startLatitude, double startLongitude, double endLatitude, double endLongitude, float[] results)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float totalKm = Math.abs(Contsants.jobEndKm-Contsants.jobStartKm);
```